# Jenkins DSL - mask password

Tags: jenkins, passwords, dsl, masking

I need to know how to perform mask password with DSL plugin - i do not want to see the password at all (not with echo  and not in Jenkins )

[this is what i did in Jenkins UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCWEd.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCWEd.png)

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

i found the way to do so :

1. add the user and password as a global credentials in Jenkins
2. use: 
   credentialsBinding {
               usernamePassword('the name of the user', 'the name of the password ', 'user's id according to Jenkins global credentials')
           }